# Create style for TextBlock in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, datagridtextcolumn

I want to create a global style that sets the `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` for all `TextBlock` controls inside a `DataGrid` or inside a `DataGridTextColumn`.

I don't want to copy the following into every `DataGridTextColumn` because it feels repetitive.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Some Property" Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I tried something like the following but it doesn't work because `DataGridTextColumn` does not inherit from `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`. `DataGrid` itself does but any further wrapping I try leads to errors:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridTextColumn">
    <Setter Property="ElementStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define a `CellStyle` as below:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And assign it to the DataGrid: `CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"`.
In this way all your cells will have content centered.

**EDIT**: The above code is from one of my projects and also contains the code to remove grid lines in the DataGrid. You can get them back by changing `Grid` to `Border` in the template. Like this:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Because I want to apply it everywhere I deleted the x:Key attribute. It works now. But it does too much. When I select a row the whole text in the row disappears (Foreground="White"?). Any ideas?

Comment: @timmkrause Did you change the `Background`? By default, when you select a row, the Foreground becomes white and the Background is blue.

Comment: That was correct before the change. The Foreground turned white and the background stayed white. I removed Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" to test things out and check if I really needed it. I do need it! Now it works! Can you explain what this binding is doing?

Comment: @timmkrause You can google for `TemplateBinding` and there are plenty of articles about it. For the usage here it means the `Background` value binds to the `Background` of the element which the template is applied to - the DataGridCell. And the `Background` of DataGridCell will be set to blue when the row is selected by a trigger. You can use Blend to check the definitions of the triggers in the default style.

Comment: By the way the style I put above is from my project and it also contains the change to remove grid lines in the DataGrid. You can change the `Grid` to `Border` in the template to get them back.

Answer (score 25):

Create a style as a static resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="verticalCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you can assign it to the ElementStyle of the DataGridTextColumn

```
<DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource verticalCenter}" />
```

Comment: What if I define the resource inside the `app.xaml`? Am I still able to refer to that in any way?

Comment: That should work out of the box, see e.g. http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/resources/ for a nice overview of your options.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToCells">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```