# WPF datagrid text wrap for all columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I know how to wrap text in dataGrid for one column .. how can I do it for all in project ... thanks ... so my code ...

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Person" Binding="{Binding Path=person}" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the code in App.XAML. This style by default will applied to all grid.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I already tried this but it doesnt know ... TargetType="DataGridTextColumn"

Comment: Just to conform, did you past the code in Application resources file?

Comment: Hi, I have edited teh answer, now try this and let me know if this helps

Comment: Yes, I put it to application.resources ... app.xaml .. and No, it doesnt work

Comment: These links may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352231/create-style-for-textblock-in-datagridtextcolumn